HTTR GET request not working - SSL peer cert not ok
I have a simple script that sends a GET request to my store's ecom API. I have tried to make this call in R, Python and cURL and all 3 return a similar error:
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK: [api.shoplightspeed.com] schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

My R code which returns the above error is as such:
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

ecom_key<-'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
ecom_sec<-'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
url<-paste0('https://',ecom_key,':',ecom_sec,'@api.shoplightspeed.com/en/')
account<-GET(paste0(url,'account.json'))

I have tried updating my cURL and also found another post that suggested to try the openssl library but this did not help either and resulted in the same error.
It's worth noting that the requests work perfectly fine in Postman, which leads me to believe there is something wrong with my machine in particular, but I want to exhaust all possible pain points.
Has anyone else faced a similar error? I have ran out of google search results.

What OS version are you using? What does curl::curl_version() return? The certificate for the URL in question seems to be signed by Let's Encrypt. Older computers might not recognized that as an authority, but most modern systems should.

Hey MrFlick, I recently updated my curl to try and solve the problem, and R recognizes that I am at 8.3.0. I am running windows 10, AMD chipset (b450, Ryzen 5 3600)

Can you access https://valid-isrgrootx1.letsencrypt.org/ from a browser? Is the computer up-to-date with Windows updates? Possibly related to this thread: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/root-cert-not-included-in-windows-10/177956/3. This seems to be really more of a computer thing than an R thing.
